# Suggestions on creating own complex() function in Python?

Tags: python

I'm working on a project in which I am required to self-create functions for converting numbers to complex, meaning I can not use complex(). Does anyone have any suggestions? Hitting a bit of a brick wall.

Comment: Your question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Types in python are just classes. You can therefore create a new type by making a class. You can create a custom class `Complex` which has properties you need by writing magic methods like `__add__` `__gt__` etc. Have a look at python's "magic methods" for more info.